# Track pad double clicking every time I single click

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad

I just bought a samsung series 7 laptop and every time I left click the trackpad a double click is registered. Is there a setting to turn this off ? I've checked mouse settings within control panel but didn't notice anything ?

When I attempt to download the driver from http://driveragent.com/c/archive/55e5143e I do not see any download link, its just displays the driver ?

Comment: What happens when using an external mouse

Comment: @Luke when using an external mouse it does not double click

Comment: @moskito-x No, ETDAniConf.exe is not on my system

Comment: @moskito-x please see quesiton edit

Comment: @moskito-x no, its not on my file system at all. I think this answers the question though so if youd like to put your comment wrt to EDTAniConf.exe I'll accept it. I'll raise a new question for actually downloading it.

Comment: Downloads are helpful in my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with EDTAniConf.exe

http://www.samsung.com/de/support/model/NP700G7A-S03DE-downloads

```
Download
Treiber
Touchpad
```

or for us

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP700G7C-S01US

```
Support Overview
Manuals & Downloads
Driver
touchpad
```

in the downloaded zip there is a folder Elan and a setup file.

Comment: Note that it does not appear possible to download EDTAniConf.exe directly from those links anymore.  Samsung instructs you to download and install "SW Update", which looks like a desktop client for making further Samsung-related changes to your system.  Very annoying.